# IE11 insecure content warning show even there are all https request

Tags: internet-explorer

Recently the browser prompt insecure content warning while one of my colleagues visit our site using ie11 (It works well in my ie11 browser). But we are using all https protocol in our site. Anyone else encounter this situation? how do you fix this?

Comment: See if this throws up anything : https://www.whynopadlock.com/

Comment: A screenshot of warning page would be helpful. Mixed content is common scenario, but maybe there's something else.

Answer (score 1):

Security warnings usually happen if one of your pages has linked resources through insecure protocol. It's called "mixed content".

Use some tools like https://www.jitbit.com/sslcheck/ for crawling your website and find the culprit.

Remember to make all your links relative like this `<img src="//www.example.com/example.jpg" alt="" />`

If that's the reason, you may display webpages without warnings because you have enabled "Display mixed content" in your IE11.

Comment: my relative links are all like this     <code>     <img src="/static/example.png" alt="">     </code>    , that`s the reason?

Comment: That's a valid relative URL. Keep it. Post a screenshot or the details of the warning.